# How to disable touch scrolling event of UnityEngine.UIElements.ScrollView?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview, mouseevent, scroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t0Rn.png)

I have used ScrollView and create a VisualElement as a child.
I want to treat mouse event on the child element.
When mousemove event of child element is called, scrolling event of ScrollView is also called.
I want to prevent scrolling event of ScrollView when dragging some part of child element.
Is it possible?

```
private ScrollView SV_SmileArea; 

public void OnMouseMoveEvent(MouseMoveEvent evt)
{
         SV_SmileArea.verticalScroller.SetEnabled(false);
        SV_SmileArea.horizontalScroller.SetEnabled(false);
}
```

It doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.